# Excel: if cell 1 contains X or Y or Z, then cell 2 should equal W

Tags: excel, excel-formula

As from the title, I need Excel to auto-populate the B row cells based on the corresponding A row cells content.

So if cell `A1` contains X or Y or Z, then cell `B1` should equal W, or if `A1` contains G or H or J, cell `B1` should equal W.

Comment: There may a typo in your description. Both of the conditions you've described involve setting the cell in column B to W. but the way it is worded, I suspect that B should be something else in the second case.

Comment: That is correct, so it should read:
So if cell A1 contains X or Y or Z, then cell B1 should equal W, or if A1 contains G or H or J, cell B1 should equal K

Comment: One IF statement works, but I can't seem to apply 2 of them, like:
=IF(OR(A1="X";A1="Y";A1="Z");"W";IF(OR(A1="G";A1="H";A1="J");"K";""))
I just get an empty cell

Comment: Sorry, my bad, it works as described by Alex

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try adding this formula to B1:

```
=IF(OR(A1="X";A1="Y";A1="Z");"W";IF(OR(A1="G";A1="H";A1="J");"W";""))
```

The first part checks if A1 is either X Y or Z. If it's true, it returns "W", if it's false, it will call for another IF statement, that checks if A1 is in G H or J. If it's true, yes, "W" again, if it's not, it'll just put nothing in there.

It's possible to simplify it, by using only one IF/OR like this:

```
=IF(OR(A1="X";A1="Y";A1="Z";A1="G";A1="H";A1="J");"W";"")
```

You might have to replace `;` with `,` depending on your locale settings.

Answer (score 4):

If the comparative values are to be hard-coded into the formula, it can be tightened up like this.

```
=IF(OR(A1={"X","Y","Z"}), "W", IF(OR(A1={"G","H","I"}), "K", ""))
```

Comment: @knuckle_sandwich - If the other Answer's formula worked without modification then I suspect your system uses a semi-colon for a list delimiter whereas I've used a comma. If that is not the issue then you've probably typed a regular bracket where a mathematical brace was required. Knowing what the error message was that you received would have helped diagnose the problem but you've decided to keep that a secret. Suffice to say that the formula was tested and was working before I posted it.

Comment: Substituting , with ; solves the problem, so the answer is correct.
As above, so the answer just now.