# if cell 1 contains X, then cell 2 should equal W, if cell 1 contains Z, then look at next criteria

Tags: excel

I am trying to transform 8 columns of dummy variables into one column of a 8 level rank.

I am trying to do so with this formular:

```
=IF(OR(A1="1");"1";IF(OR(B1="1");"2";IF(OR(C1="1");"3";IF(OR(D1="1");"4";IF(OR(E1="1");"5";IF(OR(F1="1");"6";IF(OR(G1="1");"7";IF(OR(H1="1");"8";""))))))))
```

Here is a view on the table col. 1 to 8 is the data and col.9 is what I would like my command to return:

```
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 1
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 1
0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0 5
0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0 2
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 1
0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0 7
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 1
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 1
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 1
0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0 5
```

I have used these other [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25913299/excel-if-cell-1-contains-x-or-y-or-z-then-cell-2-should-equal-w#_=_) questions as inspriration for the structure.

But it does not work, I don't get an error message, but I also don't get the right output.

Anyone who can see where the problem arises? - Would be much appreciated :)

Best wishes,
Mathilde

Comment: Use the [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MATCH-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a): `=MATCH(1,A1:H1,0)`

Comment: Dat formatting on first try +1

Comment: If the answer below was correct, please mark it as so by clicking the check mark by the answer.  It is something only you can do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the MATCH() Function:

```
=MATCH(1,A1:H1,0)
```

It appears you use `;` instead of `,` for the delimiter.  If so use this.

```
=MATCH(1;A1:H1;0)
```

[image]

Comment: I was thinking something more along the lines of `sumproduct(($A1:$H1=1)*column($A1:$H1))  but I can't argue the simplicity of match() in this case.  but it does avoid the , vs ; issue 8)

Comment: @ForwardEd that would work, but why use an array formula when not needed.  Also you would need to use AGGREGATE() or MIN(IF()), just in case there are more than one with `1` in the range.

Comment: I did scan the data first, but to be honest I did not fully read the Q so I was working with the assumption only one 1 was allowed.  TBH I thought the whole thing was a soduku setup when I first looked at it but then saw the colum count was off.

Comment: Amazing :) Thank you so much for the qick answers and good solutions. What was the world without help forums - Thanks a lot for taking the time!