# If cell 1 - 10 (range) contains X , then Cell 11 should return A or if cell range 1-10 contains Y, then cell 11 should return B

Tags: excel

Appreciate your kind help in this. If cell 1 - 10 (range) contains X , then Cell 11 should return A or if cell range 1-10 contains Y, then cell 11 should return B

I came across similar example in this forum i.e. =IF(OR(A1="X";A1="Y";A1="Z";A1="G";A1="H";A1="J");"W";"") from [Excel: if cell 1 contains X or Y or Z, then cell 2 should equal W](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25913299/excel-if-cell-1-contains-x-or-y-or-z-then-cell-2-should-equal-w) .

It is similar to what i need, but unable to search/reference a cell range using A1:A10 for instace. I have tried modifying it but keep getting errors.

Appreciate your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that all of your values are text i.e. when you say "X" you mean the letter "X" and that you are working with individual letters.

I think this is 2 problems which need to be solved together.  The first issue is getting all of the cells from 1 - 10 into a single string which we can work with.  The second is seeing if our letter is within the text.

Not sure when Microsoft added it to Excel but `TEXTJOIN()` will do the concatenation for us.  So to get all of the characters from cells A1-A10 we use `=TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,A1:A10)`.  If you want to search for strings then use a character in the `TEXTJOIN()` function that will not occur int he data set say "!". You may then need to add that character at the start and end, but you can search for things like "!a value!" within the string.

Next we need to see if our created string contains an "X".  I would suggest using `FIND` for this.  It returns an error if not found so we have to test for this.

Our function then becomes

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("X",TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,A1:A10))),"Not there","Found it")
```

There is no case statement in Excel so we have to embed the IF statement within another IF statement.  Gets very hard to read very quickly.

So to answer your initial question the full answer is:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("X",TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,A1:A10))),IF(ISERROR(FIND("Y",TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,A1:A10))),"Nothing found","B"),"A")
```

Note that it is possible A1-A10 has both an 'X' and a 'Y'.  This will look for an X first and then a 'Y'.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the simple `MATCH` formula in `A11`,

`=IF(IFERROR(MATCH("X",A1:A10,0),FALSE),"A",IF(IFERROR(MATCH("Y",A1:A10,0),FALSE),"B","No Match"))`

This `MATCH` formula searches the string "X" in the range `A1:A10`. If present, outputs the value "A". If not, searches for "Y" and outputs "B". If both are not present within the range, then "No Match" is returned. The first preference is given for "X". If both are present "X" is given more importance. Hope this helps.